# What is the difference between building C++ Builder project from IDE and command line?

Tags: command-line, ide, makefile, compilation, c++builder-5

I have different behaviour of compiler, when building project from IDE and from command-line, which I can not explain.

The detailed issue's description is rather big, but it's really simple.

I have a C++ Builder project, which has a PAS-file included (IncludeUnits.pas). This pas-file has several units and inc-files listed. These files are located in separate folders and these folders are listed in library&include paths in project's options.

Folders layout:

> C:\Demo\Bin
>   C:\Demo\Project
>   C:\Demo\Project\CBuilder5
>   C:\Demo\Project\Common
>   C:\Demo\Source
>   C:\Demo\Source\Common

Bin is output folder, Project/CBuilder5 holds project (bpr-file), Project/Common holds included pas-file (IncludeUnits.pas), Source and Source/Common hold other files (pas&inc). I think that it's pretty usual layout.

C:\Demo\Project\Common\ **IncludeUnits.pas** :

```
unit IncludeUnits;

interface

uses
  Test;

implementation

end.
```

C:\Demo\Source\ **Test.pas** :

```
unit Test;

interface

{$I Test.inc}

implementation

end.
```

C:\Demo\Source\Common\ **Test.inc** :

```
// this file is empty
```

If I compile this project from C++ Builder IDE - it will compile fine. C++ Builder IDE doesn't have any additional paths in IDE settings set.

Now, I want to compile it from command-line. First, I issue

> bpr2mak.exe MyProject.bpr

command.

This command creates MyProject.mak file, where I can see all paths ("....\Source" and "....\Source\Common" are the paths in question):

> ...
>   INCLUDEPATH = $(BCB)\include;$(BCB)\include\vcl;..\Common;..\..\Source;..\..\Source\Common
>   LIBPATH = $(BCB)\lib\obj;$(BCB)\lib;..\Common;..\..\Source;..\..\Source\Common
>   ...

Now, I run make command:

> make.exe -B -f"MyProject.mak"

It gives me the following output:

> C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~2\BIN\dcc32 -N2....\Bin -N0....\Bin -$Y+ -$W -$R -v -JPHNE -M -UC:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~2\bin..\include;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~2\bin..\include\vcl;..\Common;..\..\Source;..\..\Source\Common -D_DEBUG;_RTLDLL;NO_STRICT -OC:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~2\bin..\include;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\CBUILD~2\bin..\include\vcl;..\Common;..\..\Source;..\..\Source\Common --BCB ..\Common\IncludeUnits.PAS
>   Borland Delphi  Version 13.0  Copyright (c) 1983,99 Inprise Corporation
>   C:\Demo\Project\Common\IncludeUnits.pas(1) C:\Demo\Project\Common\IncludeUnits.pas(1) C:\Demo\Project\Common\IncludeUnits.pas(1) C:\Demo\Project\Common\IncludeUnits.pas(6) C:\Demo\Source\Test.pas(1)                 C:\Demo\Source\Test.pas(5) Fatal: File not found: 'Test.inc'

As you can see - all search path is passed to compiler and the file (Test.inc) is all here - in that Source\Common folder. But still compiler can't find it?

Of course, I run both commands from folder with bpr-file. And changing paths to absolute doesn't help.

Copying Test.inc from Source\Common to Source **will** help. Changing {$I Test.inc} to {$I Common\Test.inc} **will** also help.

Why? It seems that I'm missing something. Remember: project have no problems with compiling from IDE, Test.inc is found without copying or changing declaration. Did I miss some switch to make or dcc32?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason: command line for dcc32 misses -I switch, which specifies paths for include files.

For some reason, bpr2mak doesn't respect this option. Fortunately, it allows you to specify alternate template for conversion bpr -> mak. I edited default template and added "-I" option to it, pass new template to bpr2mak - and it worked.

Comment: +1 great idea: **copy&edit template file**, ...hope this will help in my special case - which is of a different kind